What expressions (verbs) are used for the actions of adding ingredients (solid, fluid, powdery) into a container, specifically while cooking?
Concretely, how do you describe this action: the throwing of material, either something solid like pasta, or something powdery like spices, or something fluid like cooking oil, into a container of some sort, like a frying pan or a cooking pot or a bowl.
I cannot find a match (an appropriate verb) to describe the throwing/transition of materials/fluids/ingredients into the container (mostly in cooking).
For example, how do you say the following?

Pouring flower into a bowl
Putting the pasta into the water
Throw nitrite into the test tube

What kind of verbs or expressions are used in German?

A fairly general verb is "schütten": It can be used when you make liquids move or things that come in grains:

Das Mehl in den Behälter schütten
Den Wein in den Ausguss schütten

In contrast, "gießen" is restricted to liquids (so wine is possible, but not flour).
Both verbs refer to cases in which, more specifically, you make small things or masses fall. They move by the influence of gravity.
In contrast "werfen" (throw) means that you act to impart some force on a thing, usually solid things (but there are also words like "Wasserwerfer"). This enables an horizontal movement, while "schütten / gießen" means downward movement. There is of course an area in between, so depending on how you handle the package, you might also be able to say "den Reis ins Wasser werfen" :) (but it's somewhat special). I think, for liquids, "schütten" also implies that you are using a little more force than with "gießen", I think, the resulting movement is quicker and stronger with "schütten". "Gießen" can be very slow and delicate ("der Kellner gießt Wein ins Glas" - schütten would sound rude). Moreover, "schütten" seems to require a considerable amount. So, for adding a pinch of oregano to your sauce, "schütten" would not be possible.
Your question about pasta depends on the kind of pasta. Small pieces allow "schütten". But for spaghetti, I cannot imagine saying that. Maybe it's because you would take them into your hand and put them into the pot. That's an "accompanied motion", while schütten/gießen needs independent movement, i.e. falling. Maybe it's also a factor that spaghetti are so long, they do not look "granular", not like a mass of small things. All I can think of here is "die Spaghetti ins Wasser tun" or "...geben".
I cannot answer the question about nitrit, I don't know what kind of situation this is.

Some choices not already mentioned (combine one prefix and one verb):

dazu-/hinzu- fügen/geben

For cooking recipes, I find these as well as the already given verbs somewhat lacking, since the fact, that ingredients have to be added is the obvious and boring point compared to how you do it and what to do afterwards.

unterrühren (liquids, eggs, ...)
langsam einrieseln lassen (works for sugar, flour)
nach und nach zugeben

are just a few of the terms you will find in a cookbook.

A quick look at a few recipes confirms this: [Hinzu-/dazu-, in die Schüssel] geben, [hinzu-/dazu-]fügen; replace by specific ways of adding it when important: unterheben, unterrühren, einrühren, einstreuen, unterziehen (whipped egg white). Sometimes there is no verb ("dann 300g Mehl und ein Päckchen Backpulver dazu").

I disagree regarding "unterrühren". This does not in itself confer the meaning of adding something. It only tells you to mix something already added with a pre-existing mass or liquid (e.g. you could say "Die auf dem Frischkäse abgesetzte Molke unterrühren." – the whey is already there, not added). But of course it is used elliptically in recipies (tacitly implying the action of addition).

@SebastianRiese: So would it be right to take unterrühren as roughly analogous to English mix in, as in a recipe instruction like mix in the eggs?
